# IIS + PHP url rewrite

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

Is there any way to rewrite an url of a php app on iis? If yes, how

Comment: Which IIS version? IIS6 or IIS7?

Comment: It's IIS6, so i can't use any built in stuff if i'm right