# .htaccess rewriting-url in aspx site?

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is it possible to use .htaccess url-rewriting rules in an ASPX website?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS + PHP url rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717644/iis-php-url-rewrite)

Comment: There are many questions and answers related to this on the site. Please use the search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and use the URL rewriting module for IIS:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in ASP.NET with IIS on Windows 7 or Windows XP:

- In Windows 7:

  1. Download "URL Rewrite Module" for IIS. (It’s free and available on [IIS.net](http://iis.net/))
  2. Now we have "URL Rewrite" option in IIS-7
  3. Then click on "Import Rules" option
- In XP:

  1. Install "IsAPI_RewriteManager"
  2. Then click on "Default Web Site"in the left panel
  3. Then configure the website in which .htaccess file exists. (The file contents automatically will be shown in right panel.)
  4. Then click on edit and close
  5. Then click the "Apply" button